# How to select default option from ajax value loaded woocommerce?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

How to select default option from ajax value loaded in woocommerce by this plugin?

If anyone could help me, it's will be very appreciated.

This is a code plugin:

```
 createListCity: function(data) {

        var html = '<select name="novaposhta_city" id="novaposhta_city" class="select "  data-placeholder="Select city" >';
        html += '  <option id ="empty-city" value="" >Выберите населенный пункт</option>';
        for (var city in data.cities) {
            html += '  <option value="'+ data.cities[city].city +'" >'+ data.cities[city].city +'</option>';
        }
        html += '</select>';

        if ( $( '#ship-to-different-address' ).find( 'input' ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
            $("#shipping_city").css('display', 'none');
            $("#shipping_city").after(html)
        } else {
            $("#billing_city").css('display', 'none');
            $("#billing_city").after(html)
        }
    },
```

So on this option it's loaded with many cities... but i would specify only this one: Київ

```
<option value="'+ data.cities[city].city +'" >'+ data.cities[city].city +'</option>
```

How to add to this option after loaded default value with automatic chocen of city : Київ

?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you try to do, but if you want the select option value you can get by the script .

this script will be select the option value from select dropdown .

```
        $('select #novaposhta_city').on('change', function (e) {
            var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
            var valueSelected = this.value;
           alert(valueSelected );
        });
```

or
this will be select the option value of second option from the dropdown.
you can select any option value by changing the  eq(2) to any like eq(3),eq(4) for other options values.

```
     var abc =  $("#novaposhta_city").val($("#novaposhta_cityoption:eq(2)").val());
 alert(abc);
```

it will give you second option value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's a bit different... i am asking about this:

1. When cities loaded by ajax there is so many, and i would chooce one for default Київ.
2. After this list of cities is loaded i want that default chosen "Київ".
* This is Select option field, not an input

Comment: it select the option value on change function and then select value insert into input text value .. it is just an example 

i updated my answser